# How do I get HTML syntax highlighting inside PHP strings & heredoc syntax?

Tags: php, html, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting

I'm using Sublime Text with the Pastels on Dark theme. My language of choice is PHP. How can I get HTML syntax highlighting inside PHP strings & heredoc syntax?

Comment: Still need to know how to do it with strings, but I found the answer to half of my question. In heredoc syntax you use the name of the language for the delimiters. I.E. $o = <<<HTML ....... HTML;

Comment: The above comment should be an answer, no?

Comment: If you're manipulating big HTML strings inside PHP, it feels like you're doing something weird and/or wrong.  Any large chunks of HTML belong outside the `<?php` blocks, where it gets syntax-highlighted properly..

Comment: When you add HTML outside of PHP then you have to turn output buffering on and the turn it off again to capture the HTML. Also  there will be all these snippets like: 
<?php echo $something ?>
It makes the code a lot less easy to read. I don't like your idea Mark.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Name your heredocs after the language you are using. This will syntax highlight in many text editors, including Sublime Text.

For example:

```
echo <<<HTML
<!-- put HTML here and it will have syntax highlighting -->
HTML;
```

Comment: I also just realized you can use {$myAry['subIdx']} to put any kind of variable into your heredoc syntax. Function calls can't be placed inside them but you can set the return value to a variable before the heredoc, then use that.

Comment: Also works in VSCode. Amazing!

Comment: Thank you. I really wanted to use heredoc for PHP in VSCode due to the convenience of it but was turned off by the lack of syntax highlighting and code hints. You are the man!

Answer (score -1):

Just code outside of php so you can still see the HTML syntax color-coded, and then put that html inside the php once you are done.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but "done" isn't something that really every happens to code at this company. There are always more modifications to be made.

Answer (score -1):

Wanted to add this as a comment to Ol' Reliable's answer but I am not allowed yet.

Whilst coding outside and then copying in can be a hassle, for people/editors without syntax highlighting in heredoc, an easy workaround is to temporarily add a closing php tag to the heredoc opening tag:

```
<?php
$myHtmlCode = <<<HTML?>
    <h1>I am Highlighted</h1>
    <p>Remove the closing php tag above to finish editing</p>
HTML;
?>
```