# How to use PHP code for attributes inside HTML opening tag

Tags: php, html, sublimetext3

I know this method  enables us to use PHP variables/statements for values of HTML attributes:

```
<button type="button" data-value="<?= $value; ?>">Remove</button>
```

I'm wondering what the best practice is to add them as attributes:

1. This works, but Sublime's syntax highlighter marks it as an error. See https://www.shotroom.com/2137/NPu9x for a screenshot.

   ```
   <?php
   $attributes = array(
     'title="Lorem ipsum"',
     'style="background-color: red;"',
   );
   if ($is_special_case) {
     array_push($attributes, 'data-case="special"');
   }
   $attributes = implode(' ', $attributes);
   ?>
   <button type="button" <?= $attributes; ?>>Remove</button>
   ```
2. In researching this, I learned of an alternative, but it seems to have the same problem: it works even though Sublime detects faulty syntax:

   ```
   <?php
     $tmp = ' disabled';
     echo <<<HTML
       <button type="button" ${tmp}>Remove</button>
   HTML;
   ?>
   ```

   Adding `?>` behind the first HTML is supposed to fix this, but I cannot confirm. See "[How do I get HTML syntax highlighting inside PHP strings & heredoc syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337477/how-do-i-get-html-syntax-highlighting-inside-php-strings-heredoc-syntax/36327450#36327450)".
3. Instead, I am currently using this method:

   ```
   <?php echo sprintf(`
       <button type="button" %s>Remove</button>
     `,
     ($is_disabled   ? 'disabled'   : '')
   ); ?>
   ```

   but it adds further layers of indentation, is it so much harder to read, and overall feels clunky.

Is there a better, or agreed upon alternative? Or is the first method the best one, and I just need to modify Sublime somehow, or file a bug report?

I'm using Sublime 3.2.2 Build 3211.

Comment: Sublime is probably highlighting as HTML instead of as PHP. I'll wager there's a setting that says "use the PHP highlighter for *.html files" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in your examples is the first one, **but** I suggest you implement a library for your HTML tags (like popular MVC frameworks: [Laravel Forms](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html), [Codeigniter Form Helper](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html)), for example, you might have a function to create a button with a lot of optional properties, and you should just call this function in your HTML file. It's really reusable and readable.

Answer (score 0):

You're unnecessarily complicating example #2. Try this:

```
<?php
    $tmp = 'disabled';
    echo <<<HTML
        <button type="button" $tmp>Remove</button>
HTML;
?>
```

or even better if it's really a single line of HTML:

```
<?php
    $tmp = 'disabled';
    echo "<button type='button' $tmp>Remove</button>"
?>
```

(If you simply must use double-quotes in your HTML, use:

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" $tmp>Remove</button>"
```